# Divide string based on character and count in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table as shown below

**Data1**

```
Delta,Charlie
Delta,Bravo
Bravo,Charlie
Tango,Bravo
Alpha
```

I want to get a count of the words.

So I want to get something like

```
Delta 2
Charlie 2
Bravo 3
Tango 1
Alpha 1
```

My idea is to create a temp table and split the strings based on, character and keep inserting it in the temp table based on a function defined here: [T-SQL split string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10914576/t-sql-split-string) and then group them and count them. Is there a better way?

Comment: This website helped.
http://www.sql-server-helper.com/functions/count-words.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

no need for a temp table, you can do it in one run.

see this example :

```
DECLARE 
    @tb TABLE (data1 VARCHAR(500) ) 

INSERT INTO @tb VALUES 
('Delta,Charlie'),
('Delta,Bravo'),
('Bravo,Charlie'),
('Tango,Bravo'),
('Alpha')

SELECT data1, COUNT(*) total
FROM (
SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(m.n.value('.[1]','varchar(8000)'))) data1
FROM (
    SELECT CAST('<XMLRoot><RowData>' + REPLACE(data1,',','</RowData><RowData>') + '</RowData></XMLRoot>' AS XML) split
    FROM @tb
) D
CROSS APPLY split.nodes('/XMLRoot/RowData')m(n)
) D 
GROUP BY data1
```

**More Explanation**  (per scsimon requested)

The method above is one of approaches that splits strings using XML. Basically what we did is replacing the commas from the actual data with XML tags `</RowData><RowData>` that defines each split, then concat that with another XML tags `<XMLRoot><RowData></RowData></XMLRoot>`  that define each row.

So, if we get the first row for example `Delta,Charlie` it'll be converted into :

```
<XMLRoot>
    <RowData>Delta</RowData>
    <RowData>Charlie</RowData>
</XMLRoot>
```

if you know how XML structure works or at least HTML (both have their similarities) , then you'll get the idea.

Then, we used XML techniques that SQL Server already supports, and selected the nodes (rows) , which then converted back to `VARCHAR` to be treated as single value (regular row).

This is a quick explanation, while there are a lot of other methods some of them also uses XML, it depends on your preferences.

if you need other techniques, you can [check this out](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/526912/%2FTips%2F526912%2FGenerating-and-Splitting-a-Delimited-String-Column) , which covers almost all other techniques out there. (A good article too).

If you're using SQL Server 2016 or above, you can use [STRING_SPLIT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function, which will give you the same results.

Comment: Whoopss..pretty cool and much better than my simple idea...really appreciate your time.

Comment: This is pretty complicated so an explanation would really pump your answer up 

Comment: @scsimon which part needs explanation ? it's simple approach using XML method to split strings.

Comment: You don’t see much xml in the wild (in sql server) so many people won’t understand how this works. Just my two cents. I can only name two people that use it much in answering question on SO too.

Comment: @scsimon I hope this update will give a clear explanation

Comment: Very well done 